# Calculus problem from a book of economics.

Tags: calculus, economics

Friedman proposes the following equation:

$r_{b}(0)+r_{b}(0)\frac{d(\frac{1}{r_{b}(t)})}{dt}=r_{b}(0)-\frac{r_{b}(0)}{r_b^2(t)}\frac{dr_{b}(t)}{dt}$

Where $r_{b}(0)$ is the bond interest rate at the original time,t is time and $1/r_{b}(t)$ is the bond price at a given time.

If we were to calculate the rate of change of the bond interest rate during time, wouldn't it be $r_{b}(0)\frac{dr_{b}(t)}{dt}$? Also, I cannot understand how the left side of the equation is transformed into the right side.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the financial meaning, but the transformation from LHS to RHS is quite easy to explain - it's chain rule.

$\displaystyle \frac{d(\frac 1{r_b(t)})}{dt} = \frac{d(\frac 1{r_b(t)})}{dr_b(t)}\cdot \frac{d r_b(t)}{dt} = -\frac 1{r_b(t)^2}\frac{d r_b(t)}{dt} $